# How to set background on active page on included menu?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a menu but I'm including it on every page because I don't have to copy and paste the whole code on every page. So I'm including it by this way 
    require "menu.php";

This is what menu.php contains

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
.....
<a href="news.php">News</a>
```

And I want when I'm on Index page the background of the link in the menubar to be gray for example and not just for the index.php but for every other page. I know how to do it when I'm not including it, just add class and I stylize the class. But now I can't think how it could happen.

I  would be appreciated  if someone help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to add a class to your main `<body>` (or other parent container) tag that indicates the current page:

```
<body class='page-home'>
```

Then add classes to every single menu item:

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-home">Home</a>
.....
<a href="news.php" class="nav-news">News</a>
```

Now you can write CSS styles that target your menu links differently depending on the current page:

```
.page-home .nav-home {
    /** styles for the home link when you are on the homepage **/
}
```

Now you're handling all your styling in pure CSS, and it doesn't matter that your menu is an include. It's just up to you now to decide how much styling you want to do based on the current page and the specific menu links.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this tricks:**
get your file by `file_get_contents()` and replace your class name according to your file name.
In your `menu.php` file:

```
return
'<a class=[+index] href="index.php">Home</a>
.....
<a  class=[+news] href="news.php">News</a>';
```

In your `index.php`

```
$strMenu = file_get_contents("menu.php");
$strMenu = str_replace('[+index]','is-active',$strMenu);
echo $strMenu;
```

In your `news.php`

```
$strMenu = file_get_contents("menu.php");
$strMenu = str_replace('[+news]','is-active',$strMenu);
echo $strMenu;
```